# WebSphere form based authentication logout mechanism not logging out

Tags: forms, authentication, websphere, wicket

I am analyzing code. It is a Wicket application using WebSphere form based authentication. 
The program has the ibm_security_logout form mechanism implemented. 
When being logged in, I copy the current URL to the clipboard. 
When logging out using the form, I seem to be logged out. However, when using the copied URL, I am back in the GUI, being logged in. 
So the session is still valid? How can I make sure I am actually logged out, and redirected to the login page when using 'old' URLs?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Check that security is enabled for applications in admin console, menu Security > Global security, checkbox "Application security".
- Check that there is no security interceptor in menu Security > Global Security > Trust association > Interceptor
- Connect to your application using Chrome or Firefox and open "developer tools" panel. Check what happens when you click on logout:

  1. in network tab, browser should send GET request to ibm_security_logout url
  2. in Websphere answer, there should be header *Set-Cookie:LtpaToken2=""* which should remove LtapToken2. LtpaToken2 is basically session cookie for Websphere.
  3. Look at your cookies using developer tools. LtpaToken2 should not be there anymore.

If step 1 is not OK: your client application logout button is not properly implemented.

If step 2 is not OK: there should be an error in Websphere log file.

If step 3 is not OK (very unlikely): there might cross-domain error, meaning the cookie was set for another domain name.

Comment: Benjamin thanks for this detailed procedure. It starts with the request to [the application]/ibm_security_logout url , but it is of type POST, not GET (which is as I expected, since there is a http post method in the html form declaration). Then the tools say the response data failed to load, but at the Cookies tab under 'Response Cookies' it shows the LtpaToken2 cookie with a value of "".

Comment: Also, the problem does not occur in my local development environment, it does in our OTAP test environment. So, might this be a serverside setting?

Comment: I don't know what is OTAP ... Maybe you have another authentication type configured in Websphere global security. It might be something in Global Security > trust association > interceptor ?

Comment: Ah, I am sorry, I was in a hurry and wrote 'DTAP' in Dutch by mistake. I can not find the trust association settings in the console. Also tried to follow this link, but there are no security domains configured...:  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRMWJ_6.0.0.10/com.ibm.isim.doc/securing/tsk/tsk_ic_security_sing_tai_config.htm

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Can you check that application security is enabled in admin console (menu Security > Global Security)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thanks for your reply. I believe that was the case, but meanwhile my work for this organization has come to an end... so I no longer have access to the environment, and for me personally a solution is no longer relevant. However this topic might still be of use to others.